# Trigger SelectionChangeCommitted event for ComboBox from source code

Tags: c#, events, combobox, event-handling, selectionchanged

ComboBox.SelectedIndex will trigger the SelectedIndexChanged event, is there a way to trigger SelectionChangeCommitted for a ComboBox from code?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] cb_items = { "A", "B", "C" };
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(cb_items);
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        // what code will trigger comboBox_SelectionChangedCommitted from here?
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // triggered by comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1
        textBox1.Text = "Selected " + comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Committed " + comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx) reads:

> "The SelectionChangeCommitted event is raised only when the user
>   changes the combo box selection..."

The documentation isn't always right, but without evidence to the contrary, I'll trust it today.